# Reverse of eval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, eval

I hope if someone has a bit of experience in MATLAB than I do can help here, I am a bit hopeless with this MATLAB thing.

I have a list of variable in MATLAB called `S50`, `S60`, `S70` and so...  with dimension `1x142x192`.  I simply wanted to combine them into one variable to run a statistical analysis on it (into dimension `Nx142x192`).

I found people use `eval` function to create string of variable, can I do the reverse?

```
for i = 1:5
    eval([ 'M' num2str(i) ' = M;' ]);
end
```

Comment: my first thought would be: why do you put them all in separate variables anyway? you can just use somtehing like `cube=zeros(142,192,N); for k=1,N; cube(:,:,k)=<wherever you get your data from>; end`

Comment: The orginal data were 36700x142x192, even UNIX cluster version of Matlab (8TB of memory) couldn't handle it.  I was interested in the decal statistic at the moment, hence 1950, 1960, 1970 of Threshold level or mean level (m), thank you for the help.  I will bear this trick in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't really like using EVAL, here is one possible solution:

```
%# evaluates the expression: cat(1,S50,S60,S70)
S = eval(['cat(1' sprintf(',S%d', (50:10:70)') ')']);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like magic!  Just a quick a question, why '1' not '3', surely is 3 dimension array?

Comment: @Padaiwan: from you description, the matrices are 3D where the first dimension is singleton, and you wanted to concatenate along that first dimension..

Comment: Also, if EVAL is not your preference, what would be your idea method(s)?